# Drafts appear to lock after a certain amount of time

Tags: support, documentation, documentation-drafts

Many of my drafts appear to be locked. I can’t edit, discard, or submit them. What is going on?

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/4268/alternatives-to-switch-statement-from-other-languages?draftId=52026)​ [2](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/4247/python-http-server?draftId=52009)​ [3](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/django/1661/management-commands?draftId=38735)​ [4](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/objective-c/1818/properties?draftId=35743)​ [5](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/209/list?draftId=16954)​ [6](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bash/300/hello-world?draftId=7129)​ [7](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/230/math-module?draftId=5322) ​[8](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/347/exponentiation?draftId=5321)​ [9](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/xcode/358/cross-platform-development?draftId=5297)​ [10](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/230/math-module?draftId=5293)​ [11](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/230/math-module?draftId=5280)​ [12](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/248/comparisons?draftId=4513) ​[13](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/objective-c/540/blocks?draftId=4490)​ [14](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/drafts/4333)​ [15](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/209/list?draftId=4332)

---

If I view these pages in a private browser, they are identical to:

1. [Rejected proposed change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/61643?draftId=52026)
2. [Rejected proposed change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/61627?draftId=52009)
3. [Oops!](https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/documentation/django/drafts/38735)
4. [Oops!](https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/documentation/objective-c/drafts/35743)
5. [Conflicted change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/17745?draftId=16954)
6. [Conflicted change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/7011?draftId=7129)
7. [Rejected proposed change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/4730?draftId=5322)
8. [Rejected proposed change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/4730?draftId=5321)
9. [Rejected proposed change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/4714?draftId=5297)
10. [Rejected proposed change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/4709?draftId=5293)
11. [Rejected proposed change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/4698?draftId=5280)
12. [Conflicted change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/4010?draftId=4513)
13. [Conflicted change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/3989?draftId=4490)
14. [Rejected proposed change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/3841?draftId=4333)
15. [Rejected proposed change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/3841?draftId=4332)

---

So, I guess my question is why they haven’t been removed from my profile?

Comment: Are you sure those are drafts? They look like submitted and reviewed proposed changes, given the "rejected" on each of them. (3 and 4 did not open for me, admittedly.)

Comment: @Kendra Do they redirect for you? If so, please post the redirect URLs!

Comment: For the two that are broken, or the ones that show me proposed changes?

Comment: @Kendra The ones that show proposed changes.

Comment: 1, for example, is giving me `http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/drafts/52026`. The rest are giving me the same format. Looks like the topic id and name from the urls you posted are being replaced with `/drafts/{draftId}`

Comment: @Kendra See edit.